# ASP.NET Webforms - How to determine of a request ends in a question mark ie.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

- .NET 4.51, WebForms

When I enter the URL to my WebForms app:

> http://localhost/blog/how-are-cruise-ships-powered?

and I have look at Request.URL I see the following:

[image]

and when I have a URL in the form

> http://localhost/blog/how-are-cruise-ships-powered

I see the following:

[image]

So how do I tell the two of them apart? I need to redirect the URL that has the trailing ? on it to the one that does **not** have a trailing ? but I cannot tell which one is which. Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @lc. answer, but if you still need to inspect/fetch it, you can access it through `Request.RawUrl`.

`Request.RawUrl` contains whatever is behind the slash of the domain.

e.g. `mysite.com/somepage?` would result in `/somepage?`

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is they are (semantically) exactly the same URL. `?` is a special character which serves as the delimiter between the location (address) part of a URL and its query parameters.

A trailing `?` with no parameters afterwards should function no differently as its naked counterpart, nor should it require any special redirecting/parsing/handling on a standard server, IIS included. Therefore, you should in fact not need to do anything.

If you really truly need to find the `?` character in the URL request string, you will have to do something one layer higher in the stack. But beware this breaks the generally agreed-upon semantics of the web, and sending a redirect at this point *might even cause an infinite loop on the client* depending on who is actually appending that `?`.

Comment: I understand they are semantically the same. However the SEO guys have a fit as it messes with their stats. And no amount of explaining the above makes any difference.